# Unescaped "." still matches when used in a negation group

Tags: java, regex

I made, what I believed to be, an error in a regular expression in Java recently but when I test my code I don't get the error I expect.

The expression I created was meant to replace a password in a string that I received from another source. The pattern I used went along the lines of: "password: [^\\s.]*", the idea being that it would match the word "password" the colon, a space, then any characters except for a space or a full-stop (period). I would then replace the instance with "password: XXXXXX" and therefore mask it.

The obvious error should be that I have forgotten to escape the full-stop. In otherwords the proper expression should have been "password: [^\\s\\.]*". Thing is, if I don't escape the full-stop the code still works!

Here's some sample code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SimpleRegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern simplePattern = Pattern.compile("password: [^\\s.]*");
        Matcher simpleMatcher = simplePattern.matcher("password: newpass. Enjoy.");
        String maskedString = simpleMatcher.replaceAll("password: XXXXXX");
        System.out.println(maskedString);
    }

}
```

When I run the above code I get the following output:

```
password: XXXXXX. Enjoy.
```

Is this a special case, or have I completely missed something?

(edit: changed to "escape the full-stop")

Michael Borgwardt: I couldn't think of another term to describe what I was doing apart from "negation group", sorry for the ambiguity.

Aviator: In this case, no, a space won't be in the password. I didn't make the rules ;-).

(edit: doubled up the slashes in the non-code text so it displays properly, added the ^ which was in the code, but not the text :-/)

Sundar: Fixed the double slashes, SO seems to have it's own escape characters.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing - you're not using negation groups in the text, and you talk about escaping "the space" rather than, as I think you mean, the period.

Comment: I have one query. Can't space be a password character?? Why you are excluding it?

Comment: Kurley, I think you're missing Michael Borgwardt's point: you use [^\\s.]* in the code, but [\s.]* without the ^ in the text above it. I think it's a typo in the text, please correct it as it is causing a lot of confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the point, I fixed the question for future reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A period ('.' character) does not need to be escaped inside a character class [] in a regular expression.

From the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/):

> Note that a different set of metacharacters are in effect inside a character class than outside a character class. For instance, the regular expression . loses its special meaning inside a character class, while the expression - becomes a range forming metacharacter.

Comment: That's true - but it's not his original problem, since he did originally try it without escaping.  +1 for the reference anyway, though. :)

Comment: @dtsazza: I think that _is_ his original problem - the question is about why an unescaped period works, and Avi gave the answer for it.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, I've looked at the Regex page in the java api's a lot of times and still never noticed the paragraph Avi posted. Thanks Avi.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got the negation operator mixed up for regex ranges.

In particular, my understanding is that you used the snippet `[\s.]*` to mean "any characters except for a space or a full-stop (period)."  This would in fact be expressed as `[^ .]*`, using the caret to negate the characters in the set.

I don't know if this was just a typo in your post or what was actually in your code, but the regex as it stands in your question will match the word "password", a colon, a space, then any sequence of backslash characters, "s" characters or periods.